# How do I examine f on continuity?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f$ be defined as follows:

$$f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}:(x,y)\mapsto\begin{cases}\frac{xy^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{4}}&\text{if } (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\ 0&\text{if } (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

How do I examine $f$ on continuity ?

Comment: You need to examine $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}(f(x,y))$ to examine $f$'s continuity at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate the limit of $f$ along specific lines intersecting $0$. For instance, a natural one is one where $x=y^2$, since then you (a) only have effectively one variable to care about, and (b) numerator and denominator simplify nicely.

Take $x_n=y_n^2=\frac{1}{n}$, what is the limit of $f(x_n,y_n)$?

Answer (score 0):

Take the curve $\;x=ky^2\;,\;\;k$ a constant, so that $\;(x,y)\to(0,0)\iff y\to0\;$ in this case, and

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{ky^4}{k^2y^4+y^4}=\frac k{k^2+1}$$

which shows the limit depends on the chosen particular path to the origin and thus it doesn't exist.